# Python How to modify regex to not extract phone number

Tags: python, regex

My code is:

```
import re

mid = '(?:\s+|(?:-|))'
pattern = '\(?(\d{3})\)?' + mid + '(\d{3})' + mid + '(\d{4})'

string = "1234567890"
res = re.findall(pattern, string)
print "res: ", res

for item in res:
   phone = '%s-%s-%s' % item
   print "phone:", phone
```

The print results:

```
res: [('123', '456', '7890')]
phone:  123-456-7890
```

How to modify the regex to avoid extracting phone number from "1234567890"?

Updated:
the problem is solved by removing the last '|' in the mid.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? If you want to not extract a phone number, this seems to fit the bill as it stands because there are no matches on the test input. This code overwrites a couple builtins, has missing variables and throws a `TypeError`. Please produce a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: @ggorlen  Sorry, I have corrected the code.

Comment: Thanks, but you haven't clarified what you're asking just yet. What are you trying to accomplish here? You assert your regex matches `"1234567890"` but I don't see that's the case. You're trying to *not* match that so it seems like you've succeeded.

Comment: @ggorlen  I have edited the question. The print result shows that the regex matches "1234567890", which I don't want it to match.

Comment: Okay, so your regex can be `''`. My point is it's not clear what you *do* want to match. Please specify the purpose of your regex with examples of what you want to match and what should be rejected, otherwise it's unclear how to modify it to meet your goal.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you! I removed the final '|' in regex expression 'mid' and the result is correct now.

Comment: Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
mid = '(?:\s+|(?:-|))'
```

to:

```
mid = '(?:\s+|-)'
```

and you would avoid matching `'1234567890'` because with `(?:-|)` you were match an empty delimiter in the alternate pattern.